# xmlhttp request

Tags: asp.net-ajax, request, xmlhttprequest

i have created a button as on the web browser which when clicked should execute a asp file.how do i create this!! i dont know why my xmlhttp request is not being sent.i tried this on the localhost,but still nothing seems to work!! the code goes for the button which onclick i.e the javascript goes like this!!

```
CustomButton = { 

1: function () 
{

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Default.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

i am using htdocs folder wherein the Default.asp file is located.The code of the Default.asp is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <%
="Hello World!"
%>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

why this code doesnt work????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Debug the code with the Help of Firebug script debugger on the Firefox.

Also you can analyze the request and Response by using Http Fox Addon in  the Firefox.

By using this you can see whether your request is going to the correct file or not.
also what response is coming.